# Why I'm not getting a perfect circle around an item

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to add some styling in `<p-calendar>` tag of `primeng 6.1.1`. I want a blue circle on the month item on hover.
I'm expecting this:

[image]

But instead, I'm getting this:

[image]

Why it is oval and not perfectly round. I'm using `border-radius: 50% !important`.
Here is my **datepicker.scss**

```
.ui-monthpicker-month {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #73767b;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
}

.ui-monthpicker-month:hover {
    background-color: #1474A4;
    color: white;
}
```

Please correct me.

Comment: Please make sure that the width and height is equal in size. May be show us also the HTML code for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the element is not square. Check with chrome debugger what is the width and height and make sure that both match. 
My guess is that if you change  `padding: 0px 20px 0 20px`; to  `padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;` it will be square.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify in `ui.monthpicker-month` equal height and width then change `border-radius: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;

Try by removing padding, or if you want that padding then keep same padding for all 4 sides

Comment: I made the required changes to css. But still some issues are there. Please check my answer.

Comment: have got answer ? or still need my help ? Let me know

Comment: No priyanka. I'm having some other  styling issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

width: 50px;
height: 50px;

Comment: Yes I did the same. Please see my answer.

Comment: Hi Tanzeel, Try to remove margin-top: 10px

Answer (score 0):

I'm terrible at styling but after making these changes in css:

```
.ui-monthpicker-month {
    border-radius: 100% !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #73767b;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 50px !important;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

but the month name is still somewhat pushed towards top, how to make this in exact mid position?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove margin-top: 10px; to margin-top: 0;